# gnome 3 opens only the wallpaper

Tags: gnome, gnome-classic

I changed the gnome 3 theme and it was working perfectly except the terminal, I restarted the system but now it opens only the wallpaper without any icons or bars.

I can't open any of my files.

I tried this command to restore the gnome settings but nothing:

> rm -rf .gnome2 .gnome2 .gconf .gnome2_private/ .local/share/gnome-shell/

How to fix this issue.

Comment: Do you have any graphics drivers installed?

Comment: yes and it was working fine for days, today I changed the theme and work for an hour and then restart.